# Tool for calculating profitable coin trading

Tags: trading

I want to know that if I buy 200$ worth of BTC that when I trade to other coin I'm not trading for less than 200$ worth of that coin. This way making sure I'm never loosing money.

I'm doing this manually right now but it takes forever and is not productive. Is there a tool out there to do this faster? Where I could input the amount of BTC I have and how many of the other trading coins I would get and their value in $?

I'm sure there's a term for what I'm looking for but I don't know it. Hopefully you'll get my example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a website that can convert any cryptocurrency into USD or other type of cryptocurrency

https://coinmarketcap.com/calculator/

Use this (mostly what your looking for):
https://www.currexy.com/cryptocurrency/converter

Hope this new link above found what you need, if not tell me

Comment: You can convert bitcoin into the type of cryptocurrency you want to trade then copy the coin and convert that coin into the USD

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I want something where I could input the amount of BTC I've bought and for what price (if it can't fetch BTC price at a certain date) and then select another coin, let's say ETH and it would give me the amount of ETH I could get at that moment and it's value in $.

Comment: Use the other link, it bit lag but it can convert the type of the coin into many different coin value (included USD) hope that is what your looking for

Comment: This one is better, thanks! But still misses the value of the other coins at the moment. For example, it gives the value in $ of X amount of BTC but it doesn't show the value in $ of the converted amount in ETH.

Comment: It already shown, it converted bitcoin as well as other coin matches the price of the USD (keep in mind that different website will have a slightly different prices).

Please mark the answer as acceptable if this helps you

Comment: No it doesn't show. It only shows the value of the BTC amount. For example, 0.022 BTC it shows it's worth 223$ but the correspondent amount of ETH, 0.24ETH doesn't show its value in $ (which is different from the BTC value)

Comment: You can use the first link i provided u to convert eth price to USD

Comment: Sure. It's not ideal because that's another step and takes more time. But I appreciate your effort tho. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it helped u, please mark the answer as acceptance since it helped u, marking it also help future reader who had same question know this was helpful.